# Getting a multipolygon from Overpass as a way

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo, multi-polygon

There's this Multipolygon that exists and I want to get the land area it covers so I can calculate surface area.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/12620768#map=18/42.34277/-71.12306

I have my query https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1zEV for getting all surface parking nearby, but it won't include this multipolygon and I can't seem to find a way to output this the same way I can get `ways`. Is this even possible?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "as a way". Both the OSM API and Overpass API can return something like https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/12620768/full - is this what you expected? Please clarify what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I had a general misunderstanding of how relations and ways worked. What I was really asking was how to get the relation alongside the ways in the resulting response, so I could calculate surface area of these parking lots. I'll edit my question to better clarify this

Answer (score 0):

Discovered I was able to handle this by changing `way` to `wr` to get ways and relations, which suffices to calculate land area.

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1zFe